# New to the Linux. How to update firefox and install flash player add-on?

Tags: updates, firefox, flash

I am new to the Linux System. I was able to download the update to Firefox (I think), but do not know for sure how to update it. I think my system is missing something, but being new to this operating system I not sure.

I was going to try installing another program to have a friend help me, but can't install that one either because I can't figure out how to install it. Got this laptop from someone with it installed.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using Ubuntu and the version - should appear in background at login?

Comment: New versions of Firefox get shipped out as updates on Ubuntu, after a short period of testing.

Comment: ..and regarding installing latest version of firefox, this should help: [How to install Firefox as soon as possible.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion)

Answer (score 7):

I think this should do it:

Open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, or search in the dash for 'Terminal' and open it

[image: screenshot of the default terminal]

Then enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

You will be asked for your password to give it permission to install the above stuff

`apt-get` is the command line installer included in Ubuntu. You could also use the [Software Centre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/software-center/) if it is installed. See [the manual for the Software Centre](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter#Main_window).

The package [`firefox`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/firefox/) bit installs Firefox, whilst the [`ubuntu-restricted-extras`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/) bit installs packages restricted for copyright and closed-source reasons, including Windows fonts, Java, and Flash Player. These are not always included by default.

Bear in mind that [you cannot get the latest versions of Flash after 11.2 on *any* Linux system](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/adobe-adandons-flash-on-linux).

If you really want the latest version of Flash, you [may be able to use the Windows version](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html), as you can for Silverlight.

For the latest version of Firefox, see [Ubuntu documentation on Firefox New Version](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion).

---

If `ubuntu-restricted-extras` does not work, try using this, which should install what that package should have installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer unrar gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse libavcodec-extra-53 gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly adobe-flashplugin flashplugin-installer gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

Though this should just install the flash player:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

And this might also work:

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

For any of the above, make sure all the [repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) are enabled in Software & Updates:

[image: Screenshot of repositories list]

Comment: what instructions are given are not clear. As I said I new to linux system. so i almost need step by step direction and where to find stuff like the command line installer.

Comment: ok its saids my firefox is updated but when i pull up firefox.com it saids its not but not to worried if i can get the flash player working. when i type in sudo apt-get install firefox ubuntu-restricted-extras in command line Get a message E:Cant find package. should /home/user> be at the beginng at the beginning before i type sudo apt-get install firefox ubuntu-restricted-extras

Comment: @user249605: You can add all repos like main, multiverse, etc. with this command combo.: `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse" && sudo apt-get update` and then install the _flash-player plugin_ with `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` (..a useful shortcut: after you copy the command mentioned above, you can paste it into the terminal with _Ctrl + Shift + V_)