# restoring ubuntu after a failed flash player plugin update

Tags: wireless, flash, restore

Last night I as trying to update the flash player plugin, by following the steps from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/422665/353441).

```
sudo apt-get install firefox ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Because the connection was slow and I was remaining without power, I've tried to cancel the command. It didn't get canceled so I've closed the terminal window and shout down the laptop.

Now, I can login as a root and I have access to the terminal but it has a lower screen resolution. Also I've lost wireless and wired sections on System Settings->Network.

I'll like to know if I can restore Ubuntu to the previous system state? Can I do it from the damaged state or from a LiveCD? Which is  more safety?

Answer (score 0):

Try following Command one by one in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If this wasn't fix the problem try this

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I did those commands and I think they fixed my faulty update attempts. Unfortunately it didn't fix my broken ubuntu. How can I fix the network problem first?